# Get shared link through Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I am working on an app using Google Drive. I want the user to be able to share files by link, setting the permissions to `anyone` and `withLink` as described in the [Google Developers documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert).

However, I cannot figure out what link to share. When I share a file in the Google Drive browser interface, I see the `Link to share` in the format:

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/[...]/edit?usp=sharing

A link in this format is not part of the file resource object, nor it is returned from the http call setting the permissions. I hope someone can explain to me how to get this link through the REST api?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the `alternateLink` property in the File resource to get a link that can be shared for opening the file in the relevant Google editor or viewer:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files

#### Update

[With API V3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files it is suggested to use the `webViewLink` property.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm a bit confused by how to create this File object from the intent shared by the drive app?

Comment: `aleternateLink` is no longer available in Google Drive api v3

Comment: For Google Drive API v3, Google [suggests we use](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/migration#fields) the `webViewLink` property instead.

Comment: is it possible to get the view link and not the edit link? any way we can specify this?

Answer (score 17):

To actually **enable link sharing** using [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs):

```js
drive.permissions.create({
  fileId: '......',
  requestBody: {
    role: 'reader',
    type: 'anyone',
  }
});
```

Get the `webLinkView` value using:

```js
const webViewLink = await drive.files.get({
    fileId: file.id,
    fields: 'webViewLink'
}).then(response => 
    response.data.webViewLink
);
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. Bear in mind that you could apply that permission to the whole folder so every single file will be shareable by the webViewLink

Answer (score 4):

In my case using the PHP Api v3,  for the link to be non-empty you must define that you request this field... and if you have the right permissions:

so something like this:

```
$file =self::$service->files->get("1ogXyGxcJdMXt7nJddTpVqwd6_G8Hd5sUfq4b4cxvotest",array("fields"=>"webViewLink"));
```

Comment: I'm also on api v3 (php).  I do get `webViewLink` in the API's response.  But opening that link in incognito takes me to a login screen.  Is there a way in the request of the file to say in effect "give me a link that is public to the world, good for 1 access only"?  (I'm storing images in an account that is not the web user's.)

Comment: yes, you should change the file permission after getting the file ID.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a practical example on how to get the **WebViewLink** file property (A.K.A. *File edit link*):

```
$file = $service->files->get($file_id, array('fields' => 'webViewLink'));
$web_link_view = $file->getWebViewLink();
```

OR

```
$sheetsList = $drive_service->files->listFiles([
  'fields' => 'files(id, name, webViewLink, webContentLink)',
]);

$web_link_view = $sheetsList->current()->getWebViewLink();
```

Pay attention that you should load the file specifying which fields you wanna bring with it (In this case, `webViewLink`). If you don't do that, only `id` and `name` will be available.

In case you need to adjust the file sharing settings, this is how you do it:

```
$permissions = new \Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
$permissions->setRole('writer');
$permissions->setType('anyone');

$drive_service->permissions->create($file_id, $permissions);
```

Possible values for `setRole()` and `setType()` can be found here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create

Answer (score 1):

For python, I only needed to get the file "id".
Then "created" the link like this:

```
def create_folder(folder_name, folder_id):
    """Create a folder and prints the folder ID and Folder link
    Returns : Folder Id

    """

    try:
        # create drive api client
        service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=creds)
        file_metadata = {
            "name": folder_name,
            "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
            "parents": [folder_id],
        }

        file = (
            service.files().create(body=file_metadata, fields="id").execute()
        )
        id = file.get("id")
        print(
            f'Folder ID: "{id}".',
            f'https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/{id}',
        )
        return id

    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
        return None
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix. It's important to note that this URL could change at any time, so if it is hardcoded, the change would be a breakage, instead. So collecting the value programmatically would be the best bet long-term.