# get public shareble link after uploading file to google drive using nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

i want to upload files to google drive using nodeJS as backend. I have used google drive API v3. I get the file id and type in response after uploading a file.

```
drive.files.create({
    resource: {
            name: 'Test',
            mimeType: 'image/jpeg'
        },
    media: {
            mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
            body: fileData
        }
    }, function(err, result){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);
        else
            res.send(result);
    });
```

but  what i want is when i upload a file i want it as publicly accessible. i want the shareable link of that file in response. Is there any way to do so ? i have implemented the way given here : https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing which works fine with s.showSettingsDialog(). But i want the shareable link at the time i upload the file.

Comment: got the answer. you can use the id which you get after uploading the file and then get the metadata info of that file using file id. there will be a webviewlink parameter which you need to include in the field parameter which is optional. you will get the webviewlink of that file in response.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply save this url < https://drive.google.com/open?id=FILE_ID > in your database and replace the **FILE_ID** with the actual file id stored in your google drive which in your case would be **result.id**

Comment: How to get a shareable link?
not a link through which only  the owner  of the file can access?

Comment: @Abhishek https://stackoverflow.com/a/54893611/8802812 This can help you. So basically, you ll have to set the permission as public and then the link will be accessible for everybody