# how to get a temporary download link for a file by google drive api

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-drive-api

I developed a program to store my files in google drive by using google drive api. But, I am trying to generate a temporary link of a file by google drive api, that's purpose is to allow only once time to download it. If the file downloaded by that link, then the link will be destroyed or not used anyway until a new link exist.

So is this possible by google drive api?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get shared link through Google Drive API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202163/get-shared-link-through-google-drive-api)

Answer (score 0):

I think google provide share link. you can copy that link for anchor tag.

Comment: yes, google provides, but my goal is to get a temporary link. Anybody who has the link, will not download the file, after posted the link once. The share permissions automatically disables.