# Get public link to file with Google Drive SDK

Tags: android, google-drive-api

How to use the Google Drive SDK to get a link that is accessible to everyone who has the link (public link)? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may refer with this thread: [Get shared link through Google Drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202163/get-shared-link-through-google-drive-api). If you are using v2, then you can use the [`alternateLink`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) property in the File resource to get a link that can be shared for opening the file in the relevant Google editor or viewer. While in v3, for the link to be non-empty you must define that you request this field. Also make sure that you have the right [permissions](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions).