# Sharing files in Google Drive using Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

There are plenty of resources involving sharing files in Google Drive but I can't find anything useful to Python and the references by Google aren't Python-specific.

I've saved an item ID into the variable selected_id. In this case, I want to make that file shareable by URL to anyone for reading.

```
service.permissions().create(body={"role":"reader", "type":"anyone"}, fileId=selected_id)
```

This is what I have so far but I don't think I formatted it correctly at all.

Like the title states, how would I share a file by ID on GDrive using Python? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202163/. 'alternateLink' is now ['webViewLink'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202163/get-shared-link-through-google-drive-api)

Comment: Google offers plenty of example code for popular languages. There is also documentation for the API as implemented in the client library - search for it with the additional term "pydoc"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've got the correct format as per [Permissions:Create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)

Perhaps you just need to add `.execute()` on the end?

```
service.permissions().create(body={"role":"reader", "type":"anyone"}, fileId=selected_id).execute()
```

Also is you're looking for examples using the Python API check out the following repository:
https://github.com/gsuitedevs/python-samples

I would image that you're code might look like something similar to this:
https://github.com/gsuitedevs/python-samples/blob/master/drive/driveapp/main.py#L57