# Google drive API shareable link for public

Tags: php, google-drive-api, laravel-5

I am using Google Drive API in Laravel 5.2. I am able to give access for a file to a particular email ID of Gmail. However, I want to give access publicly for all who ever have the file link.

I have tried this `webViewLink`, `alternateLink` and `webContentLink`, but all these are blank.

See Image output of file object

[image]

```
    if(isset($options['name']) && isset($options['path'])){
        $auth_con = new AuthController();
        $client = $auth_con->getClient();
        $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
        $fileMetadata = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
            'name' => $options['name']));
        $content = file_get_contents($options['path']);
        $file = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
            'data' => $content,
            'uploadType' => 'multipart',
            'fields' => 'id'
        ));
        $file_id = $file->id;
        if(isset($options['to'])){
            foreach ($options['to'] as $key => $value) {
                drive_permission($service, $value, $file_id);
            }
        }
     }


    function drive_permission($service, $email_id, $file_id)
    {
      $service->getClient()->setUseBatch(true);
      try {
        $batch = $service->createBatch();

        $userPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
            'type' => 'group',
            'role' => 'reader',
            'emailAddress' => $email_id
        ));
        $request = $service->permissions->create(
            $file_id, $userPermission, array('fields' => 'id'));
        $batch->add($request, 'anyone');
        $results = $batch->execute();
      } finally {
        $service->getClient()->setUseBatch(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Google Drive v2, use the [`alternateLink`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files) property. While in Google Drive v3, use the [`webViewLink`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) property.

Also as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42417664/5832311):

> In my case using the PHP Api v3, for the link to be non-empty you must define that you request this field, and if you have the right permissions:
>
> so something like this:
>
> ```
> $file =self::$service->files->get("1ogXyGxcJdMXt7nJddTpVqwd6_G8Hd5sUfq4b4cxvotest",array("fields"=>"webViewLink"));
> ```

Comment: thanks but it asks for login through Gmail and I have tried this before. I want to give the public access to whoever has this link.