# How to add an attachment to an event using google calendar API?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-calendar-api

I´m working with python an google API. Although this question has been asked on this site several times, most of the answers are outdated.

I've followed the guides in the documentation, for example [this one](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/create-events#python_1), but the code they provide there does not work with the lattest versions of the API. In the documentation they also say to use the [`alternateLink`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert#:%7E:text=URL%20link%20to,as%20in%20alternateLink) field, but this field doesn't exits in Drive API v3 and as they say in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15202163/get-shared-link-through-google-drive-api/15216769#15216769:%7E:text=v2/reference/files-,Update,-%5BWith%20API%20V3) the field we have to use in Drive API v3 is `webViewLink`. But when I use that field the event it's created but without any attachment and without throwing any errors.

Does anyone have updated information?

## **Edit** the code

#### Uploading the file to drive

```py
def upload_file(drive_service, file_path):

    file_name = file_path.split("/")[-1]

    file_metadata = {
        "name": file_name,
        "parents": ["id to a folder in drive"],
        "mimeType": "application/pdf",
    }
    try:
        logging.info(f"Uploading the file {file_name}")
        media = MediaFileUpload(file_path, resumable=True)
        file = (
            drive_service.files()
            .create(
                body=file_metadata,
                media_body=media,
                fields="id, mimeType, webContentLink",
            )
            .execute()
        )
        logging.info(f"File uploaded.")
        return file

    except HttpError as e:
        logging.error(f"An error occurred while uploading the file to drive: {e}")
        return
```

This function returns a dictionary with the fields `id, mimeType, webContentLink`.

#### Create the body of the event

```py
def create_event_dict(info_list, attachment = []):

    from utils import date

    start_date = date.change_date_format(info_list[0], info_list[1])
    end_date = date.change_date_format(info_list[3], info_list[4])

    if attachment:
        attachment[0]["fileUrl"] = attachment[0]["webContentLink"]
        attachment[0].pop("webContentLink")

    event = {
        "summary": f"{info_list[2]} -> {info_list[5]}",
        "location": info_list[6],
        "start": {"dateTime": start_date.isoformat(), "timeZone": "Europe/Madrid"},
        "end": {"dateTime": end_date.isoformat(), "timeZone": "Europe/Madrid"},
        "reminders": {"useDefault": True},
        "attachment": attachment,
    }

    return event
```

#### Post the event

```py
def post_event(service, event, calendar_id):
    
event = (
        service.events()
        .insert(calendarId=calendar_id, body=event, supportsAttachments=True)
        .execute()
    )
    print(f"Event created: {event.get('htmlLink')}")
    return event
```

This code doesn't throw any error but the event gets created without the attachment

Comment: Could you try printing the attachment variable and check if it's a fileID as well as checking the type if it is a string value?

Comment: @CenturyTuna the attachment variable is: `[{'id': '12kvMuR_Y', 'mimeType': 'application/pdf', 'webContentLink': 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=12kvMuR_Y&export=download'}]` is a list and inside the list there is a dictionary, the id is longer but I have cut it to publish it here. This is what `type(attachment[0]['id'])` prints `<class 'str'>` so it's indeed a string. Maybe the problem is with the fileUrl (when creating the event dictionary I change the name from webContentLink to fileUrl) that is a download link?

Comment: The `id` object in your attachment variable contains a shortened version of the file ID. Although the fileURL object parameter can either use the sharing link or the file ID, you might need to use the long version of the fileID (e.g, '1GZthTsRCckqxBgHEJlFNM7ggP8sCXV3Rr7l5JKgenFI' )

Comment: @CenturyTuna In the real program I use the long version, but I didn't want to put it here because of safety reasons

Comment: Oh I see, then it seems you might be right. "Maybe the problem is with the fileUrl (when creating the event dictionary I change the name from webContentLink to fileUrl) that is a download link?" This might be the issue since it was stated in the documentation that the key value should be fileURL

Comment: Or as long as you could build a key-pair value of `"fileURL" : "drive file ID"` for the attachment object, it should work.

Comment: @CenturyTuna but the value to `"fileURL"` is not the `fileID`, is it?

Comment: Weirdly enough, even though the parameter was set to `"fileURL"`, it still works the same even if you used the `fileID` of the pdf file.

Comment: @CenturyTuna so I have to try to pass the `fileID` to see what happends, thanks!! I will came back with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**SAMPLE:**

Here is a sample script that creates a calendar event with an attached document. Some points to consider is that currently only Google Drive attachments are supported.

Also this works after authentication.

**Service Builder:**

```
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
    from Packages.auth import OAuthCall

    def Calendar(SCOPES):
      return build("calendar", "v3", credentials=OAuthCall(SCOPES))
```

**Calendar Event Insert**

```
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from Packages.serviceBuilder import Calendar

SCOPES = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events"
]


def main():
  try:
    service = Calendar(SCOPES)
    event = {
        "end": {
            "date": "2024-02-29",
            "timeZone": "Asia/Manila"
        },
        "start": {
            "date": "2024-02-28",
            "timeZone": "Asia/Manila"
        },
        "attachments": [
            {
                "fileUrl":
                "[Insert drive sharing link here, or long version of the file ID]"
            },
        ],
        'attendees': [
            {
                'email': '[Email Address here]'
            },
        ],
        'summary':
        'Test Event',
    }
    service.events().insert(calendarId='primary',
                            supportsAttachments=True,
                            sendUpdates="all",
                            body=event).execute()

  except HttpError as error:
    print(f"An error occurred: {error}")


main()
```

**Documentation:**

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/python/latest/calendar_v3.events.html#insert

Comment: this doesn't work. It's what I have already try and the event gets created but without any attachment.

Comment: Would it be possible if you could edit your question and provide your sample code so that we can check why this doesn't work on your end?

Comment: of course, there you have it.